# How can two pucks be used at the same time in air hockey?

Tags: nisekoi

[image: Chapter 198]

As we can see, there are two pucks on a single hockey table. They collide and goal. It doesn't look like one came flying from another table. As I know there will be only one puck in a single game on a table. So what is going on in this part? Does air hockey have different gameplay rules in Japan?

What is really going on here? Can someone explain about two pucks at once on a single table?

Comment: It's possible. I have seen a table where multiple pucks rain down to the field towards the end of the game, though the table depicted in the manga page doesn't look similar. Anyway, I don't think it's strange to get a puck from somewhere and play them on a single table.

Comment: Seems like a weird table anyway, more like a multipurpose table, since it has the table tennis net there as well.

Comment: Air hockey in arcades is not always regulation, and can get a bit crazy at times: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hP7OZrczss

Comment: I know when I was small we would play with 2 because it was too easy to defend your slot with only one puck on the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical air hockey match consists of using two pushers and one puck. And as @jphager2 suggests in his comment, there's no need for a net in an air hockey match, hence, it could be a multi-purpose table.

So what's the deal with two pucks? Now, in that Chapter, Raku and Chitoge had a lot of fun in the arcade. And the bill had to be a decent amount. So instead of someone willingly agreeing to pay the bill, they keep a match on condition that the loser has to pay for all the games.

Since the the stakes were high, it is most likely that they used two pucks to increase the difficulty of the game.

Edit:

Like @mirroroftruth says in their comment, the two pucks could also be a symbolic representation of Raku and Chitoge themselves. No matter how much they try to distance themselves, they always end up coming together.

Comment: I did thought about this, i had 2 thoughts, 1 is about the difficulty level, as you state to increase the difficulty level, loser is going to play all the expenses so it would be interesting to have 2 puck and another is for the plot, as we can see, they meet each other how much they try to stay away from each other, lots of coincidence, so to end in similar manner two puck would play important role than 1 puck, so two puck were  used. This is what i think.

Comment: @mirroroftruth Yeah. I had thought about it too. But then I felt you were asking for factual details related to the game itself and not anything deep into the story. The two pucks relate their situation

Comment: ya, 1st i wanted to confirm about the game, as reading above, two pucks are possible, the reason i thought were also valid, if you don't mind then you can add it in your answer and i will accept it

Comment: @mirroroftruth: edited the answer :) (sorry it took so long)